# stored procedure calling data in a different schema

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

SQL Server 2008 R2: normally, we create our table, and stored procedure, and grant a user execute rights to the stored procedure. We never have to grant specific rights to the tables or views because if they user can execute the stored procedure SQL Server infers that the stored procedure should be allowed to perform the select/insert/update statements. Works well because we're only dealing with one schema, but now we've got a scenario where the tables are in one schema, but a stored procedure is in another. When the user executes the stored procedure, they get an error:

> Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Procedure teststoredprocedure, Line 7 The
>   SELECT permission was denied on the object 'testtable', database
>   'testdatabase', schema 'testschema'.

`teststoredprocedure` is in a different schema than `testtable`. Is it possible to allow the stored procedure to select from tables, without granting the user specific rights to those tables?

Comment: If any answer was correct or helpful please accept or upvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give the owner of the stored procedure `WITH GRANT` access to the table.

Generally a Schema is owned by a Role with the same name as the schema, so to allow `storedprocschema.teststoredprocedure` to access the table it would be:

```
GRANT SELECT on testschema.testtable TO storedprocschema WITH GRANT
```

This should work IF and only if the table is in the same database as the proc.

To achieve the same result with a table in a different database you can either:

- Enable "Cross Database Ownership Chaining"
- Move the procedure to the other database, and have a shim procedure in the original database which calls it. Then manage permissions on both procedures.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible.  Here's what you want to do:

```
alter procedure teststoredprocedure
with execute as 'UserWithPermissions'
-- rest of stored proc code
```

Where `UserWithPermissions` has the necessary permissions on your database objects that you are trying to execute CRUD operations again.

Conversely, if your database user security context has the necessary permissions, you can use the shorthand to achieve this as well:

```
with execute as self
```